# C# Ответ серверу телеграмма в телеграмм-боте

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Пишу сервер, предварительно развернув URL в ngrok. Устанавливаю вебхук с телеграммом, указываю ему свой URL и ставлю сокет на прослушку. Телеграмм присылает данные, и эти данные приходят очень много раз и судя по [этой ссылке](https://habr.com/ru/post/322078/), где написано, что

> в случае успешной обработки входящего сообщения и удачной отправки «эха», обработчик возвращает пустой ответ со статусом HTTP 200. Если этого не сделать, сервисы Telegram продолжат в течение какого-то времени «дёргать» запросами хук, либо пока не получат в ответ 200, либо пока не истечёт определённое для сообщения время.

Попытался организовать ответ со статусом 200 OK по [такому принципу](http://jobtools.ru/2013/04/pishem-svoj-vebserver-na-c/), код такой:

```
byte[] bHeader = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            "HTTP/1.1 " + "200 OK" + "\r\n"
                          + "Server: Atasoy Simple Web Server\r\n"
                          + "Content-Length: " + "\r\n"
                          + "Connection: close\r\n"
                          + "Content-Type: " + "application/json" + "\r\n\r\n");


                    handler.Send(
```

Ещё попробовал отправить ответ таким образом

```
handler.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HttpStatusCode.OK.ToString()));
```

Но проблема остаётся

Comment: `"Content-Length: " + "\r\n"` - здесь должна быть длина полезной нагрузки ответа в байтах, либо 0, если в ответе ничего нет, либо этого заголовка вообще не должно быть. Но чтобы раз и навсегда разобраться в том, как это работает, добро пожаловать в [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). Я в прошлом вашем вопросе в комментарии предлагал использовать спецификацию `HTTP/1.1`, и в этот раз предлагаю сделать то же самое.

Comment: @aepot Как мне в конкретном случае использовать спецификацию HTTP/1.1? "HTTP/1.1 " + "200 OK" + "\r\n" - этой строчки не достаточно?

Comment: @aepot а по поводу Content-lenght. Я пробовал разные варианты - и 0, и длину строки, которую потом также отсылал вместе с заголовками

Comment: Спецификация `HTTP/1.1` - это **RFC 2616**, а первая строчка - это только сообщение другому серверу или клиенту о том, что вы ее поддерживаете.

Comment: @aepot Так в чёмона заключается? в формате строки, которую я, переведя в байты, должен отправить на сервер? То есть должно быть нечто такое(пример из интернета)
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)\r\n
Content-Length: {content_length}\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n`

Comment: @aepot в итоге разобрался, видимо, я раньше посылал только заголовки, а контент нет, поэтому не работало. Спасибо за ответ!